# Validation with PHP

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to validate a form with PHP so people can't use signs and number in the name. But my code with preg_match doesn't seem to work, even though that I inserted it before the mail submits.

```
        <?php


        if (isset($_POST['navn'])) {

            $navn = $_POST['navn'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $besked = $_POST['besked'];
            $headers = 'From: kundeservice@fruithouse.dk';
            $to = 'nicolajreck@weshape.dk'; 
            $subject = 'Ny besked!';

            $body = "Fra: $navn\n E-Mail: $email\n Besked:\n $besked";

        }
    ?>

    <?php

    if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-ZÆØÅæøå]+$/i", $navn) {
        echo 'blabla';
    }
        if ($_POST['submit']) {
            if ($navn != '' && $email != '') {       
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                    echo '<p><strong>Din besked blev sendt!</strong></p>';
                } else { 
                    echo '<p><strong>Noget gik galt, prøv igen!</strong></p>'; 
                } 
            } else {
                echo '<p><strong>Du har ikke udflydt alle felter!</strong></p>';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket `if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-ZÆØÅæøå]+$/i", $navn))` <= right there.

Comment: Thanks, I've forgot to accept answers - it's done now. Thanks for pointing out the missing bracket, but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fred pointed out the syntax error.

Two potential problems that I see if you're having regex problems:

1. You're using the caret (`^`) as the beginning of the expression, not the negation (`[^a-z]`). The `A-Z` is optional with the `i` flag.
2. You need to look into unicode support for the other chars: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php
3. Test it somewhere (google 'regex tester'), and make sure the `+$` is necessary. Sometimes overly-restrictive patterns don't do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the mention. I +1 because I doubt you'll be making any *extra* points from the OP in accepting the answer, seeing his track record; so many sponges on Stack ;) *Cheers*

Comment: I've just checked it, and it's valid. I also tried with some other, but that didn't help me either.